# Data and business logic history in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, architecture, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm working on an existing Rails app, on Postgresql, that calculates commissions and various data for contractors.

Employees have many Contractors. Contractors and Employees both have fields that are used in business logic to calculate commissions.

My client wants to have a yearly snapshot of all of their data, so that they can be free to change business logic, add and remove employees, etc without losing their past (calculated) data.

My initial thought in implementing this would be Postgres schemas. I would have a cron task every year that takes the database as-is and copies every table and record to a schema for that year. That would be equivalent to simply having the older version of the DB in the future. I am worried, however, that application logic would break once columns are added in the future.

For example, a schema is created one year and a column gets added to a `contractors` table later that is used in a commissions calculation. How would I also save the old version of this commissions formula that doesn't depend on the new column?

The only solution I can think of is to simply keep the old formula and conditionally use them based on schema. I feel like this is very dirty and can lead to a lot of garbage as business logic changes.

How do you recommend I approach this problem? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have stored the calculated commision in your db to prevent recalculation. An accepted calculated value is a fact, just persist that value.

Should you need to audit the calculated fields sometime later, Im not sure the old calculation logic should be made very convenient to retrieve on application layer. You might need to trace back your code svn for this. Or the data warehouse should have the calculation logic. The application can only provide the required calculation parameters and let the auditor handle it.

If the usecase is to easily rollback to a specific historical business rules out of blue, then I wouldnt recommend to accommodate such requirement.